# GLSL/SFML - Only make portion of texture alpha

Tags: c#, glsl, sfml

I'm trying to take a portion of the current texture and turn it to 50% transparent. I send in four values, signifying the rectangle I want to make transparent. It seems every time, however, that coord.x/coord.y are set to (0, 0), resulting in the entire image being transparent when I send in any rectangle that starts at (0, 0).

I'm still new to GLSL and and probably approaching this wrong. Any pointers on the correct approach would be greatly appreciated!

**Values being sent in**

```
sprite.Shader.SetParameter("texture", sprite.Texture);
sprite.Shader.SetParameter("x1", 0);
sprite.Shader.SetParameter("x2", 5);
sprite.Shader.SetParameter("y1", 0);
sprite.Shader.SetParameter("y2", sprite.Height - 1); // sprite.Height = 32
```

**transparency.frag**

```
uniform sampler2D texture;

uniform float x1;
uniform float x2;
uniform float y1;
uniform float y2;

void main() {
    vec2 coord = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

    vec4 pixel_color = texture2D(texture, coord);

    if ((coord.x > x1) && (coord.x < x2) && (coord.y > y1) && (coord.y < y2))
    {
        pixel_color.a -= 0.5;
    }

    gl_FragColor = pixel_color;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Texture coordinates are not in pixels, but are instead given between 0.0 and 1.0.

```
gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
```

This call is giving you back a vector2f with values ranging from 0.0 to 1.0.  You are checking  pixel coordinates against normalized texture coordinates.  To solve this you can either scale your texture coordinates, or you can normalize your pixel coordinates.